# Why is the UDP message showing as ECHO?

Tags: udp, stm32, wireshark, ethernet, echo-server

I am using STM32 microcontroller for sending UDP message. I did everything about microcontroller side. I followed this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kc7OHc7JfRg&list=RDCMUCkdqtSMnhYuMsJkyHOxiPZQ&index=4&ab_channel=ControllersTech

But while i am sending to UDP message to server, i am observing ECHO protocol instead of UDP protocol on WIRESHARK. Why it seems like ECHO? Normally i have to see UDP. Is there any different reason about this result?

[WIRESHARK RESULT SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TOjM.png)

I applied UDP prossedure in STM32 microcontroller side. But i didn't see UDP protocol on WIRESHARK. I see ECHO Protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Echo protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol) is a protocol on top of UDP or TCP. Your implementation is using port 7 - which is the port reserved for the Echo protocol. Wireshark is smart enough to know this and therefore show the detected protocol as Echo. It is still UDP though as you can see from the detailed packet information in Wireshark.